# Pickle+gzip - how to utilise multiple cores?

Tags: python, gzip, pickle

I am using simple function to restore state before starting work:

```
import pickle, gzip
def load(filename):
    """Loads a compressed object from disk
    """
    file = gzip.GzipFile(filename, 'rb')
    return pickle.load(file)        
records_df = load("records_all_in_one.gzp")
```

The problem is that restoring state is the bottleneck for my application. Is there any simple way to tell gzip/pickle combination to utilise multiprocessing?

Of course, I can always split the data structure and read it from multiple files on multiple cores but I would rather see if there is more clever way to do it.

Last bit of information - the data being restored is a large pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

You could run a [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) subprocess, which is a parallel implementation of gzip.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be to run a parallel gzip implementeation and use python to process the uncompressed data.

You could use subprocess to run a gzip instance or use pipes and read in the data through stdin.

Comment: that sounds good - is there a parallel version of gzip for python? I would like to keep it as much platform-independent as I can

Comment: @petr What I think he meant was to utilize the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: @JAB still - you need to have the gzip binary somewhere, not a python-only solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `cPickle` instead as it's [up to 1000 times faster than `pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#relationship-to-other-python-modules)

Comment: Depending on the version of Python he's using, `pickle` could very well just be a wrapper around `cPickle` if it's available. (Python 3 does this, I believe.)

Comment: Here we go, first line at http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html#relationship-to-other-python-modules. It's `_pickle` rather than `cPickle` now, though.